# Go Fiber Middleware cannot find route if I chack if user is superuser

Tags: go, middleware, go-fiber

First I'm checking if user is loggedin using the AuthMiddleware which is also called from the first if block. Later, I'm trying to allow all the users from middleware that has superuser permission as follows.

```golang
func HasPermissionMiddleware(expectedPermissions ...string) fiber.Handler {
    return func(c *fiber.Ctx) error {
        if authError := AuthMiddleware()(c); authError != nil {
            return authError
        }

        user := c.Locals("user").(models.Users)
        if !user.HasChangedInitPassword {
            return c.Status(fiber.StatusUnauthorized).JSON(fiber.Map{"message": "Please change the initial password first"})
        }
        if !user.IsSuperuser {
            return c.Next()
        }
        if !HasPermissions(expectedPermissions, user.Permissions) {
            joined := strings.Join(expectedPermissions, ", ")
            log.Printf("Requires %s access", joined)
            return c.Status(fiber.StatusUnauthorized).JSON(fiber.Map{"message": "Insufficiant permission access"})
        }
        return c.Next()
    }
}
```

and use it as with my routes as

```golang
func UserManagementRoutes(app *fiber.App) {
    router := app.Group("api/users")

    router.Get("/", middlewares.AuthMiddleware(), controllers.GetUsersListHandler)
    ...
    router.Get("/permissions/:id", middlewares.HasPermissionMiddleware("permissions_view"), controllers.AllPermissionOfUserHandler)
    ...
}
```

When I hit the details api postman throws the follwoing error:

```bash
Cannot GET /api/users/1
```

But If I remove `if user.IsSuperuser{}` block from middleware it do response successfully. It seems like, if i return something from inside that block it throws the error.

Comment: can you add your code to some repo and share, so that we can debug as it seems problem in middleware.

Comment: Hey thanks for you query. Actually I solved it. I was calling AuthMiddleware from HasPermissionMiddleware. Which is why when It enters trys to return c.Next() it's context gets nullified.